# Computer freezes surfing the web

Tags: 12.04

OS - 12.04 64 bit
RAM - 8 GB
CPU - Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz × 2
10 GB Free space

Just surfing the web my **cpu%** goes to 80% and my **mem%** goes over 50% and then the OS freezes and I have to Alt&SysRq REISUB to start again.  This happens consistently when I go to sites with lots of pictures and video.  Here is my PSTREE:

```
init─┬─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
     │                ├─dnsmasq
     │                └─2*[{NetworkManager}]
     ├─accounts-daemon───{accounts-daemon}
     ├─acpid
     ├─aptd
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bamfdaemon───2*[{bamfdaemon}]
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─cav───14*[{cav}]
     ├─chrome─┬─chrome
     │        ├─chrome─┬─chrome
     │        │        └─2*[{chrome}]
     │        ├─chrome-sandbox───chrome─┬─chrome─┬─chrome───8*[{chrome}]
     │        │                         │        └─chrome───5*[{chrome}]
     │        │                         └─chrome-sandbox───nacl_helper
     │        └─41*[{chrome}]
     ├─cmdagent───26*[{cmdagent}]
     ├─cmgdaemon───3*[{cmgdaemon}]
     ├─colord───2*[{colord}]
     ├─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-dae}]
     ├─cron
     ├─cupsd
     ├─2*[dbus-daemon]
     ├─dbus-launch
     ├─gconfd-2
     ├─geoclue-master
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─gnome-keyring-d───7*[{gnome-keyring-d}]
     ├─gnome-terminal─┬─bash───pstree
     │                ├─gnome-pty-helpe
     │                └─4*[{gnome-terminal}]
     ├─goa-daemon───{goa-daemon}
     ├─gvfs-afc-volume───{gvfs-afc-volume}
     ├─gvfs-fuse-daemo───3*[{gvfs-fuse-daemo}]
     ├─gvfs-gdu-volume
     ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo
     ├─gvfsd
     ├─gvfsd-burn
     ├─gvfsd-metadata
     ├─gvfsd-trash
     ├─hud-service───3*[{hud-service}]
     ├─indicator-appli───{indicator-appli}
     ├─indicator-datet───2*[{indicator-datet}]
     ├─indicator-messa───{indicator-messa}
     ├─indicator-print───2*[{indicator-print}]
     ├─indicator-sessi───2*[{indicator-sessi}]
     ├─indicator-sound───2*[{indicator-sound}]
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─lightdm─┬─Xorg───2*[{Xorg}]
     │         ├─lightdm─┬─gnome-session─┬─bluetooth-apple───2*[{bluetooth-appl+
     │         │         │               ├─compiz─┬─sh───gtk-window-deco───2*[{+
     │         │         │               │        └─4*[{compiz}]
     │         │         │               ├─deja-dup-monito─┬─deja-dup───3*[{dej+
     │         │         │               │                 └─3*[{deja-dup-monit+
     │         │         │               ├─gdu-notificatio───2*[{gdu-notificati+
     │         │         │               ├─gnome-fallback-───2*[{gnome-fallback+
     │         │         │               ├─gnome-screensav───2*[{gnome-screensa+
     │         │         │               ├─gnome-settings-───2*[{gnome-settings+
     │         │         │               ├─nautilus───2*[{nautilus}]
     │         │         │               ├─nm-applet───2*[{nm-applet}]
     │         │         │               ├─polkit-gnome-au───2*[{polkit-gnome-a+
     │         │         │               ├─ssh-agent
     │         │         │               ├─telepathy-indic───2*[{telepathy-indi+
     │         │         │               ├─update-notifier───2*[{update-notifie+
     │         │         │               ├─zeitgeist-datah───{zeitgeist-datah}
     │         │         │               └─3*[{gnome-session}]
     │         │         └─{lightdm}
     │         └─2*[{lightdm}]
     ├─mission-control───2*[{mission-control}]
     ├─modem-manager
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─pulseaudio─┬─gconf-helper
     │            └─2*[{pulseaudio}]
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
     ├─ubuntu-geoip-pr───2*[{ubuntu-geoip-pr}]
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     ├─udisks-daemon─┬─udisks-daemon
     │               └─2*[{udisks-daemon}]
     ├─unity-applicati───2*[{unity-applicati}]
     ├─unity-files-dae───2*[{unity-files-dae}]
     ├─unity-lens-vide───{unity-lens-vide}
     ├─unity-music-dae───{unity-music-dae}
     ├─unity-musicstor───{unity-musicstor}
     ├─unity-panel-ser───3*[{unity-panel-ser}]
     ├─unity-scope-vid───2*[{unity-scope-vid}]
     ├─upowerd───2*[{upowerd}]
     ├─upstart-socket-
     ├─upstart-udev-br
     ├─whoopsie───{whoopsie}
     ├─zeitgeist-daemo───{zeitgeist-daemo}
     └─zeitgeist-fts─┬─cat
                     └─{zeitgeist-fts}
```

Comment: Please post the last lines on dmesg. Or if you want to see what happened on the previous session post the last 20 to 30 lines of /var/log/syslog.1 or /var/log/dmesg.0

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is normal. Ubuntu is CPU intensive on its own remember! Try using midori, a lightweight browser.

Comment: what is your GPU are you using intel or nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while you're getting to the bottom of this, instead of `RIESUB` - you could `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and `killall -9 chrome` - and then `Ctrl+Alt+F7` ---

I dealt with this for a long time, and I never did find the culprit. 
Ultimately, I found that it was a Chrome plugin ---- while I never found which one was causing the issue - after disabling several unnecessary plugins/extensions, it stopped freezing.

Eventually, I had other problems and I had to revert all of my chrome settings to stock -- which wasnt as bad as I though.

If you want to test this without removing/disabling anything, simply run Chromium along side your Chrome browser -- and you'll likely get the same results as me.

Good luck - !

Answer (score 0):

Go to this url:

```
chrome://flags
```

and enable the option to "override software rendering lists" ( it's like the first option )

scroll to the bottom of the page and select restart to apply the changes

Go to the url

```
chrome://gpu
```

to see if there are any issues

Installing some open gl, gl rendering / decoding / acceleration packages may be needed for full gpu support.